# Need to check the meaning of a Transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the transition matrix just the change of basis matrix from a **non-standard** basis to the **standard basis**?

Answer (score 0):

No.  A transition matrix can convert between any two bases $B$ and $C$.

Source: *Elementary Linear Algebra with Applications, 3rd ed.* by Richard Hill.  Page 220.

Comment: thanks, ok so if we have two non-standard bases, B1 and B2 and we are asked to find e.g the transtion matrix From B1 to B2 we need to know a vector in B2 right other wise we can't do the calculation?

Comment: @user134785 If you know a basis of B1 and B2, you could do the calculation.

Comment: Actually i'm completely confused now its not what I thought it was, how exactly do I find the transition matrix?